# Create two tables with space between

Tags: html, css, html-table

How can I add these two tables beside each other with a space between them.
With the code below they are right beneeth each other. But they need to beside each other with space between them. Is this possible and cant anyone help me out.

```
<style type="text/css">
    .tftable {
        font-size:       12px;
        color:           #333333;
        width:           100%;
        border-width:    1px;
        border-color:    #729ea5;
        border-collapse: collapse;
    }

    .tftable th {
        font-size:        12px;
        background-color: #acc8cc;
        border-width:     1px;
        padding:          8px;
        border-style:     solid;
        border-color:     #729ea5;
        text-align:       left;
    }

    .tftable tr {
        background-color: #d4e3e5;
    }

    .tftable td {
        font-size:    12px;
        border-width: 1px;
        padding:      8px;
        border-style: solid;
        border-color: #729ea5;
    }

    .tftable tr:hover {
        background-color: #ffffff;
    }
</style>

<table class="tftable" border="1">
    <tr><th>Header 1</th></tr>
    <tr><td>Row:1 Cell:1</td></tr>
    <tr><td>Row:2 Cell:1</td></tr>
    <tr><td>Row:3 Cell:1</td></tr>
    <tr><td>Row:4 Cell:1</td></tr>
    <tr><td>Row:5 Cell:1</td></tr>
    <tr><td>Row:6 Cell:1</td></tr>
    <table class="tftable" border="1">
        <tr><th>Header 1</th></tr>
        <tr><td>Row:1 Cell:1</td></tr>
        <tr><td>Row:2 Cell:1</td></tr>
        <tr><td>Row:3 Cell:1</td></tr>
        <tr><td>Row:4 Cell:1</td></tr>
        <tr><td>Row:5 Cell:1</td></tr>
        <tr><td>Row:6 Cell:1</td></tr>
    </table>
</table>
```

Is it also possible to add an break in the header because I tried this:

```
<tr><th><br />Header 1</th></tr>
```

But that didn't work?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I created a demo fiddle for you, the error is that you are coding the tables wrong. Here is the correct code:

```
<table class="tftable" border="1">
<tr><th>Header 1</th></tr>
<tr><td>Row:1 Cell:1</td></tr>
<tr><td>Row:2 Cell:1</td></tr>
<tr><td>Row:3 Cell:1</td></tr>
<tr><td>Row:4 Cell:1</td></tr>
<tr><td>Row:5 Cell:1</td></tr>
<tr><td>Row:6 Cell:1</td></tr></table>

<table class="tftable" border="1">
<tr><th>Header 1</th></tr>
<tr><td>Row:1 Cell:1</td></tr>
<tr><td>Row:2 Cell:1</td></tr>
<tr><td>Row:3 Cell:1</td></tr>
<tr><td>Row:4 Cell:1</td></tr>
<tr><td>Row:5 Cell:1</td></tr>
<tr><td>Row:6 Cell:1</td></tr>
   </table>
```

Take a look to this DEMO

https://jsfiddle.net/wgrLfxg3/6/

Comment: He is right they will display: inline by default when you do them right haha nice catch!

Answer (score 0):

How about this.

```
.tftable {
 float: left;
 margin-right: 5%;
 width:45%;
}
```